# How to get data passed from a form in Express (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to get data that are passed from a page using a form and use that data in the page that is redirected.

I have this form in my client side:

```html
<form action="game" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and I have this script in my server:

```js
app.get('/game',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/game.html'); 
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `method='get'` instead of `POST`?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Use `bodyParser.urlencoded(`) middleware:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Then the form values will be on req.body:

```
app.post('/game', function (req, res) {
    res.render('the_template', { name: req.body.name });
});
```

Setting `{ extended: true }` allows the bodyParser to accept json like data within the form data including nested objects. e.g. `{ person: { name: Adam } }` sent using javascript rather than the name value pairs which traditional HTML form send. If you don't need that you can set the extended value to false. Not defining an extended option (i.e. using a default setting) is apparently deprecated and they seem to want you to decide whether you need nested options or plain name value pairs.

If you want to be able to parse form data for some routes and json data for others in your express server, you can use:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: <true|false> }))
```

`urlencoded()` for x-www-form-urlencoded content type

- `true` - for nested data structures
- `false` - for name value pairs

`json()` - for application/json content type

Note that form/multipart needs a different body parser (such as multer)

**Update: fix if you get ExpressJS Error about Body-Parser being Deprecated**

Replace

```
app.use(bodyparser.json()); //utilizes the body-parser package
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

By

```
app.use(express.json()); // Used to parse JSON bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded()); //Parse URL-encoded bodies
```

Comment: Why `extended: true` is set? Are we expecting something special to receive?

Comment: You have a very detailed answer for it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175465/body-parser-extended-option-qs-vs-querystring

Comment: Bodyparser seems to be marked as @Deprecated

Answer (score 35):

> IMPORTANT: This is deprecated, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38763341) is the correct solution.

---

To allow express to handle form data nicely you need to ensure you have `bodyParser` included like so:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
//the rest of your configuration
```

Then in your POST handler you can access the form body through the `Request.body` property like so:

```
app.post('/game', function (req, res) {
    res.render('some-file', { name: req.body.name });
});
```

Also you'll need to use a templating engine (such as [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)) if you're intending to output the form data in the response.

Comment: how do i access the data in the client if for example i have jade?

Comment: how do i get the name variable?

Comment: @JudeCalimbas This solution is correct for `POST`, but you have `GET` in question. If you change that, you can access `name` in `req.body.name` as @Slace has in his answer.

Comment: yes Ive changed it to post already and got it working. but my problem is how do i access name in my game.html?

Comment: This has since been changed to:
`var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: Not true~ to parse form data you'll need ```bodyParser.urlencoded()```

Answer (score 24):

or you can simply use express to do so:

```js
   const express = require('express')
   const app = express()

   app.use(express.json()) // for json
   app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // for form data
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The bodyparser library is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access variable names in your views, you should use the `res.render` function and pass the variable like:

```
res.render('game', {
    name: req.body.name
}
```

and then in jade do

```
div!= name
```

Comment: u can use ejs too, if u want. or maybe read the html file and replace the placeholder for name

Answer (score 0):

In `index.html` file:

```html
<div class="col">First name
  <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" aria-label="First name">
</div>
```

Include these two middleware in your main file to get data from the form into express

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

So we can get data using:

```js
console.log(req.body.firstname);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get it working using **GET** method, u should use `req.query`:

```js
app.get('/game',function(req,res){
    res.render('relative/path/to/rendering/template', { name: req.query.name });
});
```

Using GET method is perfectly reasonable and even advisable to search for a specific object and display it later on a web page.

However to modify, create or delete objects, **POST** method is the way to go as it is more secure.

You can read more about the differences between the two [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).