# body-parser - extended option (qs vs querystring)

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

In the current version of [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser), the `extended` option when using `bodyParser.urlencoded()` is now required. In the README, it explains:

> The extended option allows to choose between parsing the URL-encoded data with the querystring library (when false) or the qs library (when true).
>
> [...]
>
> Defaults to true, but using the default has been deprecated. Please research into the difference between qs and querystring and choose the appropriate setting.

I couldn't find any helpful or specific information on this. I only found a deprecated [node-querystring](https://github.com/tj/node-querystring).

Should this option just always be true?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45690436/3290143

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The reason for this message is that `body-parser` is [about to change default value for `extended` from `true` to `false`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/45).

Extended protocol uses [`qs` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) to parse `x-www-form-urlencoded` data. The main advantage of `qs` is that it uses very powerful serialization/deserialization algorithm, capable of serializing any json-like data structure.

But web-browsers don't normally use this protocol, because `x-www-form-urlencoded` was designed to serialize flat html forms. Though, it may come in handy if you're going to send rich data structures using `ajax`.

[`querystring` library`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystring) provides basic serialization/deserialization algorithm, the one used by all web-browsers to serialize form data. This basic algorithm is significantly simpler than extended one, but limited to flat data structures.

Both algorithms work exactly the same with flat data.

Now, when you know pros and cons of both algorithms, it's up to you to decide which one suits your application better.

Comment: just like to comment that `extended: false` messes up 2D arrays :(

Comment: @woojoo666 it's because basic serialization/deserialization algorithm doesn't support nested data structures.

Comment: Yeah I know haha, just wanted to say that for any fellow googlers out there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960764/what-does-extended-mean-in-express-4-0

Comment: When you say nested you mean to something like `person[name]=John&person[age]=49` ?

Comment: @MáximaAlekz yes