# How to work body parser and express session NodeJs Middleware functions

Tags: node.js, express

I have started to working on MEANJS technology. I have been not clear about some functions of body-parse and express-session. I also go through their official site but not still clear. That functions are:-

> bodyParser.urlencoded({
>       extended: true });
>
> bodyParser.json()
>
> expressSession({   resave: true,   saveUninitialized: true, })

In some place it will `bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })` and `expressSession({   resave: false,   saveUninitialized: false, })`. Now when use these `boolean`, please explain this with **example**. So it will more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Middleware [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser):

In general this middleware will parse the bodies of incoming HTTP requests and populate the `req.body` property which is then available in your routes and middlewares.

`body-parser` provides different parsers for different types of request bodies. If you write the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

The first `app.use()` will include the JSON body parser and the second one will include the URL-encoded form body parser. The parsers you will need depend on the request types your server has to deal with. The difference regarding `extended: false` and `extended: true` is already explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29177740/5112436).

Middleware [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session):

This middleware provides an easy way to handle sessions and session data in your express app. The two configuration properties `resave` and `saveUninitialized` influence the way `express-session` stores the session data of your users.

**Example:** Assume a new user is visiting your web site. `express-session` detects that this user does not have a session yet so it will create a new one which only contains a session ID and no data. If you set `saveUninitialized: true` this session will be stored in your session store without containing any real session data. `saveUninitialized: false` will store the session as soon as it actually contains some values. (simply said)

**Example:** Now assume a user with an existing session is visiting your web site. Some resources are requested but the user's session data does not change. `resave: true` will store the unchanged data anyway whereas `resave: false` will not.

**Summary:** Setting `app.use(expressSession({resave: false, saveUninitialized: false}));` will reduce the number of times your session store will be accessed which is a benefit regarding hardware resources and performance. So in most cases you will want to set them to `false`.