# Express JS: POST request to insert at DynamoDB

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, amazon-dynamodb

I have to insert following data in a DynamoDB table using express framework in a node.js application

```
register.html

<input type = "text" placeholder="First Name" id = "txtFirstName"><br><br>
<input type = "text" placeholder="Last Name" id = "txtLastName"><br><br>        
<input type = "email" placeholder="Email" id = "txtEmail"><br><br>
<input type = "text" placeholder="Phone" id = "txtPhone"><br><br>
<input type = "text" placeholder="Zip Code" id = "txtZip"><br><br>
```

I understand I need to use express `body-parser` as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304888/how-to-get-data-passed-from-a-form-in-express-node-js/38763341#38763341)

But it is not clear to me how to create the JSON that I need to insert in a DynamoDB table  using the `body-parser` approach described. I  can do this with jQuery to read those html items and create a JSON. For example, I need to create a JSON like below:

```
var paramsInsert = {
                TableName:tableName,
                Item:{
                        "email": email,
                        "info":{
                                "FirstName": fName,
                                "LastName": lName,
                                "Phone": phone,
                                "ZipCode": zip
                        }
                }
        };
```

This `paramsInsert` is eventually passed to DynamoDB to insert into a table like below

```
insertAtTable(paramsInsert);
```

How do I create `paramsInsert` using the `body-parser` approach?

EDIT:
Following [this link](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-express-rest-api/) I wrote below code but still not getting the output

```
app.post('/register.html', function(req, res) {
  const { fname, lname, email, phone, zip } = req.body;
  console.log(fname)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the `name` attribute on the input elements:

```
<input type = "text" placeholder="First Name" id = "txtFirstName" name="firstName">
<input type = "text" placeholder="Last Name" id = "txtLastName" name="lastName">      
<input type = "email" placeholder="Email" id = "txtEmail" name="email">
<input type = "text" placeholder="Phone" id = "txtPhone" name="phone">
<input type = "text" placeholder="Zip Code" id = "txtZip" name="zip">
```

With the `name` attribute specified, you should now be able to do the following:

```
app.post('/register.html', function(req, res) {
  const {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    phone,
    zip
  } = req.body

  const paramsInsert = {
    TableName: 'example',
    Item: {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      phone,
      zip
    }
  }
}
```

This can be shorten by using [ES2018's object spread](https://twitter.com/mathias/status/956970099063189505):

```
app.post('/register.html', function(req, res) {
  const paramsInsert = {
    TableName: 'example',
    Item: { ...req.body }
  }
}
```