# How to stop special characters in HTML text box?

Tags: javascript, html

I have below HTML form...If I put characters like ! or ^ or £ in the password text box, my server gets different characters including %...How it is possible to get "exactly" same characters for password in my server...

if I entered password as abc!£^hg^! , my server gets password as abc%21%C2%A3%5Ehg%5E%21

```
   <form autocomplete="off" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got an encoding configuration issue on your server.

Answer (score 3):

Form data has to be encoded *somehow* for transmission over HTTP.

URL encoding is the default for forms. In that format, some characters are encoded using [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

You need to solve this by using server-side code that handles the encoded form data properly, not by trying to hack things so the data isn't encoded.

Any language you might use for server-side programming will have libraries (or built-in approaches) for solving this.

Take, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304888/how-to-get-data-passed-from-a-form-in-express-node-js) about reading form data when the server-side code is written in JavaScript and uses the Express.js framework. It uses the `urlencoded` middleware from the `body-parse` module to decode the data.