# Express.js req.body is null when form submitted

Tags: node.js, postgresql, forms, express, request

I have a simple html form:

```
<div class="signup-form">
  <h2>Signup for an account</h2>
  <form method="POST" action="/submit-signup">
    <input type="text" title="username" placeholder="username" />
    <input type="password" title="username" placeholder="password" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

and an index.js with routes:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'user',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'app',
  password: 'password',
  port: 5432,
})


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname +'/index.html');
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname +'/login.html');
});

app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname +'/signup.html');
});


app.post('/submit-signup',(req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  const username = req.body.username
  const password = req.body.password

  pool.query('INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ($1, $2)', [username, password], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${result.insertId}`)
  })
})


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

Every time the form is submitted with answers the request body logs as {} and the error is thrown from the query because of the null value (the column in my database is set to not-null). I've tried most fixes from old stack overflow posts, so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `body-parser` middleware. This middleware by default will try to parse every http body into a js-object based on a given json value.

As you are sending your data over an HTML form this data is not in JSON representation, but in the data generated by the HTML form.[Mozilla Specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

To make this work you either need to iplement a way to read the body sent by the HTML form or use a more modern approach by sending a (REST) JSON request to your express server.

- To make your code work use `body-parser.urlencoded()` as HTML form data is an url encoded text [Ref to existing Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304888/how-to-get-data-passed-from-a-form-in-express-node-js)
- To make your form a bit more modern, use a JavaScript framework and follow a client-server pattern. Have a look at this tutorial [REST tutorial with express](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/rest-api-tutorial-rest-client-rest-service-and-api-calls-explained-with-code-examples/)

Comment: The issue was that I needed to add {extended:true} for the urlencoded bodyparser to work. The existing stackoverflow answer helped me figure that out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem cuz you don't use a **name** tag in HTML form.

```html
<div class="signup-form">
  <h2>Signup for an account</h2>
  <form method="POST" action="/submit-signup">
    <input type="text" name="username" title="username" placeholder="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" title="password" placeholder="password" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add name attribute in your html input field