# Is there a way I can extract formData on nodejs backend from post request coming from vuejs frontend?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, http-post, multipartform-data, form-data

My request body looks as shown below. Am trying to get filename, uploadedBy and csv file and save to my local machine as csv.

------WebKitFormBoundarypm79CqkInUFFrKPU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"

sample.csv
------WebKitFormBoundarypm79CqkInUFFrKPU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedBy"

someEmail@email.com
------WebKitFormBoundarypm79CqkInUFFrKPU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="sample.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

------WebKitFormBoundarypm79CqkInUFFrKPU--

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304888/how-to-get-data-passed-from-a-form-in-express-node-js) answer your question?

Comment: Please share your code in order to get a better help. It could be more than one way to address your problem, so it would be better if we provide you an answer based in your code so far.