# How to redirect a form request without adding another layer of browser history?

Tags: express

So, I am building a website using express.js, ejs, node.js etc. Mainly express.js, so when I use a form submit I don't want to go to another route, or path, instead, stay on the same page just reload it.

Can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The action attribute of the form will be where the POST request goes when the form is submitted (if not specified, it will be the current page route). You can handle this with `app.post()` in the server file.

```js
app.post("/some/route", (req, res) => {
  ...
});
```

To receive the form inputs in the req.body, see here: [How to get data passed from a form in Express (Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304888/how-to-get-data-passed-from-a-form-in-express-node-js/38763341#38763341)

Once you have done the server side handling of the form, you can redirect the page back to your form page, but with variables that will tell the user what has happened. You can do this by either using query variables (eg `?error=403` in url), or you could render them in the page using the ejs embedded javascript.

For example, render the `login.html` page sending the variable error as true

```
app.post("/some/route", (req, res) => {
  // request handling...

  res.render(path.join(__dirname, "public/login.html"), {
    "error": true
  });
});
```

Then in login.html,

```
<% if (error) { %>
  <p>Error!!</p>
<% } %>
```

To the user, the page will not appear to have changed, unless redirected to a different page. If using query variables, the only difference will be the added `?error=403` in the url.

Hopefully this helps.