# How to get form data in html, i get a black response

Tags: html, forms, request

I have this form in my html

```
<form action="/data" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Car VIN" required>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Car Mileage" required>
   </div>

   <div class="col-12">
   <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox d-block mb-2">
   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2">
   </div> 

   <div class="col-12 col-lg-4"></div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn amado-btn w-100">submit</button>
```

and this in my app.js file

```
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
    app.use(express.json());
    
    app.post('/data', (req, res, next) => {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    });
```

but when i input data in the form, i get an empty json in the terminal. Please can anyone help?

Comment: Can you try this middleware `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))` ? This answer might help @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304888/how-to-get-data-passed-from-a-form-in-express-node-js

Comment: I still get a blank json result

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `name` attribute.
Non of your form fields have `name` which will be keys for key-value body object.

```
<form action="/data" method="POST">
    <input name="car_vin" type="text">
    <input name="car_mileage" type="text">
    <input name="custom_check" type="checkbox">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

When sending HTML form you are not sending JSON request but `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so you should use `urlencoded({extended: true})` as comment above suggested and explained in the ExpressJS docs:  https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body.

Before any change, please try in terminal:

```
$ curl -v -d name1=val1 http://localhost:3000/data
```

you should get response:

```
{"name1":"val1"}
```

Comment: It work, now I know, thank you so much. I love it here, super helpful